# Spring Condition is not able to access property available in properties file

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I am trying to access properties in condition class for decision making.

In debugging I found that Condition class is loaded as a bean and loading before  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

My Intention is to load beans depends on condition. I have tried couple of resources and articles but not found any solution.

```
@Component(value="customAuthenticationProvider")
@Conditional(CustomCondition.class)
```

Below is the condition class code.

```
public class CustomCondition implements Condition {


@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    String property = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("auth.enable.providers");

    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(property) && property.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                return true;
    }



    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: did you debug your customCondition class , what if all specified conditions are matching.

Comment: @Shailesh yes I debug for positive and negative scenario. If condition is true it is allowing to create a bean otherwise false. But inside condition class i am not able to access my properties file.

Comment: you haven't posted code of condition class , might be there is something missing , edit the question and post  pseudo code for condition class

Comment: did sysout property & context on console, what do you get on console, had you been using spring boot i would have suggested to use conditionalonproperty : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

Comment: we are not using springboot and we may not need those.

Comment: also I notice a case difference in your class name, like @Conditional(customCondition.class) uses 'c' with lower case however code you posted uses 'C' with upper case , hope it's typo

Comment: How about trying @Order annotation for your condition.?

Comment: Just a quick question -> are you configuring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in static method? AFAIK Spring logs some warning if that is not the case.

Comment: @Povel  I configured using this class- org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in xml as a bean

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried loading properties file inside the condition class and accessing properties.

I would highly appreciate if someone can suggest a better answer.